# Access a record's data to fill in form_for text_fields on Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning RoR 4 on my own and I have been stuck for a while with this issue.

I have a form that gather a Student's information. I would like to autofill many of the fields if the Student specifies info from the existing database. For example, there is a drop down of available school's to which the student can choose to attend that is stored in the School model. When the student selects a school, I am trying to populate other fields in the form with the values of that School selection so the user does not have to specify it again.

I do not understand how to design my form in a way to allow me to grab the data and store the values in the fields.

I would appreciate any resources and help as I have been searching for a while!

Comment: You should include code to show effort taken by.

Comment: without any code it is quite difficult to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could respond to on_change event at the select box. Then all you need to do is send get request somewhere into Schools controller to get info about particular school and using javascript on the frontend again parse the response and put it into appropriate fields.